# What are the most commonly used colors for References and Cites?

Tags: hyperref, color, best-practices

Here's a little excerpt from the thesis I'm working on:

[image: thesis]

The LaTeX template was provided by my university, and it defaulted to superscript brackets with blue numbers for cites and red for anything that is a reference.

I know how to change this stuff on the fly. I also have full permission to change the template as I please, it's not a requirement. So I was wondering if the blue and red colors are common or not. To me, it just feels... wrong? It's hard to describe.

What are the most commonly used colors for links in scientific papers for LaTeX?

Comment: I think the most common thing is no color at all.

Comment: Off topic: it should be “Galerie” in German, with only one “l”.

Comment: If it is not a requirement,  it is a matter of taste and therefore off-topic here. Said that, I prefer black for printed versions and very dark colors for PDF (e.g. `blue!30!black`) so you can still see the link but it is not so distracting as the pure red of the image. I do not understand german, but *as is*, it seems that the "most important part" of text of the image is "Abblindung 3.3." The question is: Do you really want to highlight this part so much?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks, it's really confusing with "gallery" in English having two L and German only one.

Comment: @Fran I like that idea! Seems like the best of both worlds for what I'm looking for, because the links just blend in too much, which can be a real annoyance when reading it as a PDF.